Docker random volume creation
I have the following docker compose :
services:
  db:
    container_name: Postgres_Server
    image: 'postgis/postgis:latest'
    restart: always
    volumes: 
    - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: routingfinder
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  pgadmin:
    container_name: PgAadmin4
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:8.13
    restart: always
    volumes: 
    - pgadmin:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - rabbitData:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - rabbitLogs:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
        - rabbitmq_go_net
networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  dbdata:
   name: myDBDataVolume
  pgadmin:
   name: myPGDataVolume
  rabbitData :
   name: myRabbitData
  rabbitLogs:
   name: myRabbitLogs

This generates the correponding volumes + a not named one with the following :
{
    "CreatedAt": "2024-11-14T11:20:24Z",
    "Driver": "local",
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.volume.anonymous": ""
    },
    "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/7b51284e5bf24fcf3ba6abae63b3f10a28cecde08781f5ae3610acab2224a3e7/_data",
    "Name": "7b51284e5bf24fcf3ba6abae63b3f10a28cecde08781f5ae3610acab2224a3e7",
    "Options": null,
    "Scope": "local"
}

This is seen after a docker volume prune -a to start from scratch.
So I have 3 services and 4 volumes should be created.
Does someone know where this not named volume can come from?
Many thanks in advance.
PS : When inspecting the volume I am getting:
[
    {
        "Id": "a7baeacb008a9ac8fda66136a6ea7584de1fda920e21adcebf97fbcf8040b329",   
        "Created": "2024-11-14T15:35:24.679409272Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "postgres"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 13254,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2024-11-14T15:35:24.831942066Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:08d9a1b66edb76839d9dd5c0c5192f73f2e859c8356de5f719ddcde1b2207223",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a7baeacb008a9ac8fda66136a6ea7584de1fda920e21adcebf97fbcf8040b329/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a7baeacb008a9ac8fda66136a6ea7584de1fda920e21adcebf97fbcf8040b329/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a7baeacb008a9ac8fda66136a6ea7584de1fda920e21adcebf97fbcf8040b329/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a7baeacb008a9ac8fda66136a6ea7584de1fda920e21adcebf97fbcf8040b329/a7baeacb008a9ac8fda66136a6ea7584de1fda920e21adcebf97fbcf8040b329-json.log",
        "Name": "/Postgres_Server",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "route-find_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": [],
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Source": "myDBDataVolume",
                    "Target": "/data/postgres",
                    "VolumeOptions": {}
                }
            ],
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware",
                "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/861fa3c684f5d70e042f7faffb0e1e1c0209eadbd535b58c1c50c9d2d0bf0dbf-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2d30bc44b992d4b0cbc11dafbe2f01a1e327fe0c2df84d77c0f08fd5daba047b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b277aa31baa92e3d37ae5574e5337712cdd630836e2bdaec8f5c937ba8f95492/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/747b9b0defbffab43dfe86f5dc72f7da248c70afc1f47c78706d63b6737a029c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6f9fb4926202f546910fb0c8fdafe91d110eb49d7f91d102e7fbc8a64dd09d97/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a0c8f5aeba2f6f421ca15dbe7fb82fc0ba997f1dbe94796b2b63ff98b437fe49/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0eef92e3e7ae8e49139b843f205d84139b6e7d47edef5a7b3be5ca56b1b08115/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/944e10d5c22723a985d65b4f1e7f6291458cedc352aa4cc86dfed3538a97c974/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6826f4c45fba7f51b9dc7a68f488f4cf034a702a8f502eddbf7b7e9af5a728f8/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/eeecd44050af576bf13524a5c51d3977f5579579aaca9e4da3eeffde12345bde/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f8ad9f4d1424e1fe6a828be301d9752d46b2f91589aeb5b33f1ac604eda603a3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e8d18170da08bf21e71619eda8686013fe1602707e54ed0c827e82e6eec8b81f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4796b0e5608d3c81ca94515b7fbc5ce0682d157fe9e2b6ae06666e5ffcb5a2bf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/be56c9c5f5cd06f3557d638d2e07f9261e3b1afcfd2110148cc73035e817fe69/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/56ef1f0d455181e3caebcd662731623c0e54dee888c4365f05a5294aefc2b8e5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d398a847347dc0539bfa016ffca4de3b4a26c4daeccd84bb8c3e02381f41b4d7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a80b08c19c59d5a3338c73b102f9a223d11ce7b7a34605b6b5fbafccc080247a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a33d40236039989a070e181fbb0b7499b2e6b6b8c924acebc214ed5b80761ec7/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c7f01391f91369148a063fc67855e43d607ac92e7057c8139ea57a4d01fb55c8/diff",        
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/861fa3c684f5d70e042f7faffb0e1e1c0209eadbd535b58c1c50c9d2d0bf0dbf/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/861fa3c684f5d70e042f7faffb0e1e1c0209eadbd535b58c1c50c9d2d0bf0dbf/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/861fa3c684f5d70e042f7faffb0e1e1c0209eadbd535b58c1c50c9d2d0bf0dbf/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "myDBDataVolume",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/myDBDataVolume/_data",
                "Destination": "/data/postgres",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "6cd33b4d21e86b97e344cc70aa585171af4f767c5877e5334d355b728d8842c6",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/6cd33b4d21e86b97e344cc70aa585171af4f767c5877e5334d355b728d8842c6/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "a7baeacb008a",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PGDATA=/data/postgres",
                "POSTGRES_USER=root",
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root",
                "POSTGRES_DB=pass",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/postgresql/17/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.17",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=17",
                "PG_VERSION=17.0-1.pgdg110+1",
                "POSTGIS_MAJOR=3",
                "POSTGIS_VERSION=3.5.0+dfsg-1.pgdg110+1"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "Image": "postgis/postgis:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "c0a60f43ff08e14f4db00dfd0e86cc20c9ef026b43591d4a9ad3c2cd9a2f4a0a",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
                "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:08d9a1b66edb76839d9dd5c0c5192f73f2e859c8356de5f719ddcde1b2207223",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "route-find",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "D:\\projects\\route-find\\docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "D:\\projects\\route-find",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "postgres",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "2.29.7",
                "maintainer": "PostGIS Project - https://postgis.net",
                "org.opencontainers.image.description": "PostGIS 3.5.0+dfsg-1.pgdg110+1 spatial database extension with PostgreSQL 17 bullseye",
                "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/postgis/docker-postgis"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGINT"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "a63b41a8b411659326b6f16675c743ba2967f9ddbb502e919047892847348ac1",
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/a63b41a8b411",
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5432"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "route-find_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "Postgres_Server",
                        "postgres"
                    ],
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null,
                    "NetworkID": "f87af1b44d5376fc4b290b889e419a9e5066ec27a5fb7c2d1918923b3bfc16c1",
                    "EndpointID": "b625f53b46d8f34fd4753caaf2db9d822902144e8185ada32c742434a31c0d25",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "DNSNames": [
                        "Postgres_Server",
                        "postgres",
                        "a7baeacb008a"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

With no clue ...

The labels hint it's an anonymous volume, probably created via a Dockerfile VOLUME directive.  If you knew which container it was connected to, and looked at that image's documentation or Dockerfile, you could probably find the associated container path.  Is it causing any sort of trouble to your application?

Update:
The pgadmin4 Dockerfile has the mount
VOLUME /var/lib/pgadmin 

(Line 228 Dockerfile)
in your fist docker-compose.yml the mountpoint was wrong (top post)
volumes: 
    - pgadmin:/var/lib/postgresql/data

in your new docker-compose.yml (new post below) it's correct.
volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

Delete the anonymous volume, restart everything and it should be ok.

docker volume prune -a removes all unused volumes.
Is the volume still in use? Check docker ps what is still running after stopping those 3 containers.
Also check locations of your docker-compose.yml files docker compose ls .
Backup the volume or check what's inside i.e. /var/lib/docker/volumes/7b5../_data - then try to delete it manually with docker volume rm 7b5 this might give you a message like "cannot delete volume 7b5, it's used by <container-id>.
docker inspect <container-id> will help you to find out more.

I have edited the question with docker inspect result

Here is the final compose file that is working fine:
services:
  postgis:
    image: 'postgis/postgis:17-3.5'
    container_name: PosgresServer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: lastkm
    volumes: 
      - local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:8.13
    container_name: PgAadmin4
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    container_name: 'RabbitMQ'
    ports:
        - 5672:5672
        - 15672:15672
    volumes:
        - rabbitData:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
        - rabbitLogs:/var/log/rabbitmq
    networks:
        - rabbitmq_go_net
networks:
  rabbitmq_go_net:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  local_pgdata:
    name: postGresData
  pgadmin-data:
    name: pgAdminData
  rabbitData :
   name: myRabbitData
  rabbitLogs:
   name: myRabbitLogs

